# How to get admin user name get null?

Tags: magento2

How can I make this function run - also when getUsername() is null

```
$authSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
$UUsername = $authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
```

Answer (score 1):

We should not be using Object Manager as this can cause issues. For getting admin username we are going to want to add these classes to our constructor.

```
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ....
}
```

then we can get our user like this:

```
$this->authSession->getUser()
```

this will give you the current logged in admin.
You can later get the details like `$user->getUsername()` or `$user->getEmail().`